# Send Dictionary to iCloud using Key-value

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, icloud

I am using this code for writing a dictionary to iCloud.

```
 [[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore]
     setDictionary:dictCloudTables forKey:@"Tables"];

 [[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore] synchronize];
```

And i am fetching dictionary from cloud using this code:

```
 dictCloudTables = [[[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore]
                      dictionaryForKey:@"Tables"] mutableCopy];
```

It always gives me dictionary that i have inserted for the very first time.

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code (except you don't check the return value of `synchronise`). I think what might be wrong is your expectation of what *should* happen. Here's an extract from the documentation:

> This method does not force new keys and values to be written to
>   iCloud. Rather, it lets iCloud know that new keys and values are
>   available to be uploaded. Do not rely on your keys and values being
>   available on other devices immediately.

Comment: How much time it generally takes to update on other devices, assuming they have proper internet.

Comment: It's not really that simple. They _seem_ to coalesce updates, meaning if you send lots of updates in a short period of time, it will probably take longer to see them on other machines (as it'll be waiting for further updates). On the other hand, just one, isolated update much sync pretty much straight away. In short, if you _need_ a known latency, iCloud isn't the solution; you need to implement your own.